# Get policy permissions using botocore

Tags: amazon-web-services, botocore

How can I get list of services that have permissions in a given policy using botocore. We can see list of services in web console but how to get in botocore.
Screenshot is attached for reference.[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBMJP.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving the Policy document of a user, role or group is defined below

1. Create an IAM client

   ```
   client = session.create_client('iam')
   ```
2. Then Depending on if it's a role, user or group you can retrieve the Policy document define for that role, user or group.

   response = client.get_user_policy(
   UserName='string',
   PolicyName='string')

   Retrieves the specified inline policy document that is embedded in the specified IAM user.

   ```
   response = client.get_role_policy(
   RoleName='string',
   PolicyName='string')
   ```

   Retrieves the specified inline policy document that is embedded with the specified IAM role.

   ```
   response = client.get_group_policy(
   GroupName='string',
   PolicyName='string')
   ```

   Retrieves the specified inline policy document that is embedded in the specified IAM group.
3. All three return the Policy Document that will list the services that role/user/group can access.

User:

```
{
    'UserName': 'string',
    'PolicyName': 'string',
    'PolicyDocument': 'string'
}
```

Role:

```
{
      'RoleName': 'string',
      'PolicyName': 'string',
      'PolicyDocument': 'string'
 }
```

Group:

```
{
    'GroupName': 'string',
    'PolicyName': 'string',
    'PolicyDocument': 'string'
}
```

[get_user_policy](http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_user_policy)

[get_role_policy](http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_role_policy)

[get_group_policy](http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_group_policy)

[IAM Policy Document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html)

Comment: thanks for your response but I want to get only services that a user have permissions not full policy document as shown in the screenshot and wants to get for all policies even if they are not inline attached.

Comment: The policy document explains what service the Entity has access too, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_permissions.html